# How do I number gird arrays for battleship game?

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to implement numbers from 0-9 along the top and left hand side of my Battleship ocean. I would like it to look like this

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
0|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+  
1|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
2|
 (you get the idea!)
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I have tried a number of if loops with no real result. I can get the numbers to display, but not the way I would like.

```
public void printOcean(boolean showShips) {
    for (int row = 0; row < OCEAN_SIZE; row++) 
    {
        if(row == 0)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < OCEAN_SIZE; i++) 
            {
                System.out.print(String.format("%4s", i));
                System.out.println();
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.print("+---");        
                }
                System.out.print("+\n");
                System.out.print(row +" ");


                for (int col = 0; col < OCEAN_SIZE; col++) 
                {
                    System.out.print("| " + ocean[row][col].printCoordinate(showShips) + " ");
                }
                System.out.print("|");
                System.out.println(); 
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < OCEAN_SIZE; i++) 
        {
            System.out.print("+---");           
        }
        System.out.print("+\n");
    }
}
```

I am hoping to see something like below

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
0|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+  
1|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
2| etc.
```

However the result I get is

```
    0
 +---+
0 |
   1
 +---+
0 |
   2
 +---+
0 |
   3
 +---+
0 |
   4
 +---+
0 |
   5
 +---+
0 |
   6
 +---+
0 |
   7
 +---+
0 |
   8
 +---+
0 |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: for humans, rows and columns usually start with 1

Comment: quite simply, your loops are out of order.   Shift your final loop into the main loop, instead of doing it afterwards. - I just put your code into a text editor, you need to fix your indentation and brackets too.  For example, you have an extra scope brace for no reason

Comment: You might find it helpful to separate out each 'type' of line as a separate method. One method to print the column headings, one to print a line of horizontal gridding (`+---+...`) and one to print the vertical bars and cell spacings (which presumably will also need to print out the battleships and stuff). Get those methods working individually and you should find it much easier to print the overall structure you're aiming for.

Comment: A tip for you, break down your code into separate functions. - I suggest `drawCell(x,y)` that handles the contents, `drawCellLine()` to draw the numbered lines (calling `drawCell()` as part of it) and `drawInterCellLine()` to draw the `+---+` pattern.  Then you just need to have a parent function that calls them in turn.

Comment: Thanks Baldrickk, looks like I have some work to do!

Comment: And piggybacking on the above comments, breaking those things out into separate functions will help you keep the for loops straight, because right now there are some things inside that need to be outside. You won't have to think as hard about nesting. And it will be easier to fix each routine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. But somewhere you should customize it.

```
public class Main {
    static int OCEAN_SIZE = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printOcean(false);
    }

    private static void printColumnIndexes() {
        System.out.print("  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < OCEAN_SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    private static void printBorders() {
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < OCEAN_SIZE; j++) {
            System.out.print("+--");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void printRows(boolean showShips) {
        for (int i = 0; i < OCEAN_SIZE; i++) {
            // printing row indexes
            System.out.print(i + "|");

            // printing main body
            for (int j = 0; j < OCEAN_SIZE; j++) {
                // Here you can put your ships
                if (showShips) {
                    // print your ship
                    // from your ship map[i][j].
                    // mention that cell size from your 
                    // sample is 2. So it should be something
                    // like this: "* " or " *" etc.
                    // if (map[i][j]) {
                    //     System.out.print("* |");
                    // } else {
                    //     System.out.print("  |");
                    // }
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  |");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();

            // printing extra borders after row filled
            printBorders();
        }
    }

    private static void printOcean(boolean showShips) {
        printColumnIndexes();
        printBorders();
        printRows(showShips);
    }
}
```

It gives me:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
0|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
1|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
2|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
3|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
4|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
5|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
6|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
7|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
8|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
 +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--
```

So, you can customize `printRows()` method to fill your ships.

Comment: I'd still add a new function to print the cell contents, rather than customising `printRows` directly (it should call that new function though)

Comment: from the original example, it looks like OCEAN_SIZE was 10 there.

Comment: @Baldrickk, you're right. I just give some template. So, user should add extra method to print cell contents. It is better to derive logic.